# Record id and contact id?

Tags: apex, case, contact, record

I have a record id.  How can I use that in an an Apex function to retrieve the contact id?

Background: I have a react app that I have embedded using lightning container static resource (aura component) and using LCC npm module.  I am getting the record id from the aura component using a part of this code snippet:

```html
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"> 
    <!-- handlers-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:card title="Lightning Aura Component">
    <div class="slds-p-around_small">
        Current Record ID in Lightning Aura Component: <strong>{!v.recordId}</strong> <br/><br/>
    </div>
    my static resource is here 
    </lightning:card> 
</aura:component>
```

I still need to figure out how to pass the record id to my static resource single page application (react app).  In my react app, I am calling Apex using LCC npm module.  I am able to access all the contacts.  I want to use the record id to select the active contact.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the documentation, you can pass in the value on the query string:

```
<lightning:container src="{!$Resource.myReactApp + '/index.html?recordid=' + v.recordId}"/>
```

Your app then just needs to read this value:

```
let recordId = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&')
  .find(param => param.split('=')[0] === 'recordid').split('=',2)[1];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! (For this and the other questions).  I still don't know how to use the record Id to get the contact id.  I have access to both contacts and cases through apex.  I see that the docs state that the cases has a field called 'RecordTypeId' - is that the same thing?

Comment: @Nour No, RecordTypeId is for specialization of one type of record (e.g. Business Contacts vs Personal Contacts). In Apex, you can use getSobjectType on an Id variable to determine what type of record you've got an Id for, and then make a determination as to how to find the contact from there.